# How to match from beginning in css nth-of-child selector?

Tags: css

I want to select the first `div` until `div` number three.

So I use this selector:

```
div:nth-of-type(1) ~ div:nth-of-type(3) {
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

But it only match the 3 div. why? how to match from the begining until 3?

```css
div:nth-of-type(1) ~ div:nth-of-type(3) {
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `:nth-child` selector with `-n+X` pattern, where `X` is first `X` number of elements you need to target.

```css
div:nth-child(-n+3) {
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
```